# How to show extra dynamic field along with all model fields inside StackedInline Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to display a dynamic link inside `StackedInline` admin class. How can I do this if the dynamic field is not part of the model.

This is my code -

```
class HistoryInline(admin.StackedInline):
    verbose_name_plural = 'History'
    model = Import
    fields = ('link',)
    extra = 0
    readonly_fields = ['link']

    def link(self, obj):
        url = ...
        return mark_safe("<a href='%s'>click here</a>" % url)


class CatalogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__str__', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    inlines = [ImportInline, HistoryInline]
    exclude = ('app')
```

Get Error:
`Unknown field(s) (link) specified for Catalog`

I tried adding the function name inside `fields` but it didn't work.
Also tried `list_display` but it seems to be not available for `StackedInline`

How can I make it show me all the model fields as well as the extra dynamic link ?

Answer (score 0):

@S.K you can also try adding the field as a method to the model and implement it that way.

For Example:

```
class SomeModel(model.models)
    name = models.CharField
    age = models.Int

    def colored_name(self):
            return format_html(
                '<span style="color: #{};">{} {}</span>',
                self.color_code,
                self.first_name,
                self.last_name,
             )

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age', 'colored_name')
```

docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

you can also change **mark_safe** with **format_html**

If the string given is a method of the model, ModelAdmin or a callable, Django will HTML-escape the output by default. To escape user input and allow your own unescaped tags, use format_html().

Comment: Also, the admin logic should reside inside admin class only. But it gives me the error `Unknown field(s) (link) specified for CatalogAdmin`

Comment: What you also can do is move the def link(): to the CatalogAdmin and leave the rest as is.